# Extract content with RestAssured from pdf

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, rest-assured

I have Spring Rest Controller which returns pdf file

```
fun getContent(): ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> {
        val content = documentService.getContent()
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"${UriUtils.encode(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)}\"")
            .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
            .header("Pragma", "no-cache")
            .header("Expires", "0")
            .contentLength(fileContent.contentLength())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
            .body(fileContent)

    }
```

Then I would like to write test with RestAssured, extract content with PDFBox and do some assertions. So far I have

```
def response = given().get("url").asByteArray()
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(response))
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("test.pdf"), response)

try {
  return new PDFTextStripper().getText(document)
} finally {
  document.close()
}
```

but I get an exception `java.io.IOException: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid block type`. Writing it to file with `FileUtils` saves as empty pdf but file downloaded directly from controller via browser or postman is ok. Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: DataFormatException means a broken / corrupted PDF. Btw you can pass the byte array directly. Make sure you're using the latest version of PDFBox, which is 2.0.27. It would be interesting to compare the binary from the original PDF and the "saved as empty pdf", maybe this will give a hint to what happens.

Comment: Yup, pdf was corrupted because of some custom filter attached to RestAssured specification which was manipulating content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pdf was corrupted because of some custom filter attached to RestAssured specification which was manipulating content